# Attach an event handler to the document, no document tag so can't use a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have now gotten the hang of creating custom directives and adding event listeners to my DOM elements but now I want to add an event listener to the `document`. There is no `<document>` tag obviously so I can't use a directive, or maybe there is some special trick?

The listener will be for dealing with a click on the document and it will need access to the `$scope` if possible because it needs to find out what dropdowns are currently open so it can close them.

Comment: Bind on the body instead.

Comment: I did that already but the problem was if the content on the page is not taking up 100% of the height of the viewport the event does not get triggered but when the event is on the document the event gets fired even if the content is not taking up the whole viewport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject `$document` into your directive:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function ($document) {

  return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log(scope);
      console.log($document);
    }
  }
})
```

Then use the directive on any element, depending on which scope you want:

```
<html ng-app="myApp" my-directive>
```

Comment: Ah yes I see now, I think. So could I attach this directive to the body for example, DI the `$document` into this directive and then in the `link` method attach my event listener to the `$document` and it would then have access to the `scope`?

Comment: To clarify, the scope passed to the link function will be the scope currently associated with the body tag in that case. Most likely the rootScope unless you are using ng-controller on the body tag.

Comment: That's great. There is always a bit of uncertainty as to how things are supposed to be done the first few days of learning a new framework but I'm really starting to see how things work now. I nearly put DOM manipulation in a controller on day one! Thanks.